# c++ set console text color to RGB value

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application

I want to set the text color of the console to a RGB color.
I created a function to get the ColorTable of the console and change the colors in it, but it doesn't work. I don't know how to set the text color to a value from the color table so I just change the whole color table, but it doesn't do anything.

```
void setColor(int r, int g, int b)
{
    COLORREF cr;
    cr = RGB(r, g, b);
    PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX ci;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX cir;
    ci = &cir;
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsole , ci);
    cout <<hex<< ci->ColorTable[2];
    for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
            ci->ColorTable[i] = cr;
    }
    SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsole, ci);

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsole , ci);

    cout <<endl <<  ci->ColorTable[2];
}
```

In `main()` I invoke the function multiple times, but the output is the same every call and the color doesn't change. `SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx()` and `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx()` don't seem to do anything, `ci` remains unchanged when they are called.

What do I do wrong?

Also, if it worked I assume the background color would also get changed because I change the whole pallette, so how do I set the text color to a specific value from the color table, e.g. i put `ci->ColorTable[2] = cr;` in the `changeColor()` function instead of the for loop, how can I set the text color to the color that is now stored in `ColorTable[2]`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is useful, but you could take a look at related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285825/how-to-change-text-or-background-color-in-a-windows-console-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053837/c-colors-in-console-different-colors-in-different-text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `SetConsoleTextAttribute` to set the current text color and background color, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047(v=vs.85).aspx for details.

Comment: thanks, but with this function I don't have RGB colors. I just found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509278/rgb-specific-console-text-color-c, the accepted answer tells to modify the color table like I tried to do and then select the color from the color table via `SetConsoleTextAttribue` (if I understood it correctly). However I don't get the color table modified.

Comment: have you checked the return value of `SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx`? to see if it's succeeding? And called `GetLastError` if it's failing?

Comment: just tested, `getlastError()` returns `0x57` which is `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` for both `SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` and `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx`. Any Idea why the parameter could be Invalid? Maybe I'm using the wrong handle?

Comment: no you forgot to set the cbSize member of the `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX` structure you're passing in

Comment: thanks, works now. I assume I can only have 16 different colors at a time. is that right?

Comment: According to the structure definition yes it appears that is the case

Answer (score 4):

A Windows console color  table looks like this:

```
Color            Background Foreground
---------------------------------------------
Black            0           0
Blue             1           1
Green            2           2
Cyan             3           3
Red                  4           4
Magenta          5           5
Brown            6           6
White            7           7
Gray             -           8
Intense Blue     -           9
Intense Green    -           10
Intense Cyan     -           11
Intense Red          -           12
Intense Magenta  -           13
Yellow           -           14
Intense White    -               15
```

To set background colors you have to combine the foreground color code with 
the background color code using this equation:

```
finalcolor = (16*backgroundcolor) + foregroundcolor
```

if you want to set a text color that has a blue background and white text
you simply look up the color code in the table. Blue is 1 and white is 15;

Hence `int backgroundcolor=1;` and `int foregroundcolor=15;`

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

void setcolor(int color)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),color);
    return;
}

int main()
{

    int foregroundcolor=15;
    int backgroundcolor=1;
    int finalcolor;

    finalcolor=(16*backgroundcolor)+foregroundcolor;

    setcolor(finalcolor);
    cout<<"finalcolor=(16*backgroundcolor)+foregroundcolor\n";
    setcolor(7);

    return 0;
}
```